# Table of tables..use SQL pivot to extract unique fields for each table

Tags: sql-server, pivot

new to stack overflow as my job has me doing more SQL querying than I'm use to (super basic queries). And since this is the best online resource....:)

Preamble...my company has developed an SQL database that contains a giant table of tables. In other words, they extracted a series of tables (200+) from external sources and put them all into one massive table to be used for reporting purposes in other systems. For example, if one of these external tables has 5 fields and 10 rows of data, that translates to 50 rows in this 'table of tables' (Table1, Field1, Value...Table1, Field2, Value....TableX, FieldX, Value...etc.)

Requirement...I need to 'pivot' the data for the purposes of getting a list of all the fields in all the tables. In other words ignore the values (just TableX, FieldX). I need to do this in order to find 'like' fields across all the tables. Being new to using PIVOT in SQL queries, I know the basic structure of the SQL query, but I'm getting lost in the organization of it.  Maybe I don't even use PIVOT. Here's what I have...

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT [FieldName],[iModelTable]
  FROM [H352090DataMart].[dbo].[HA_iModelTableData] 



PIVOT (MAX([FieldName]) FOR [iTableName] IN 
  (
--not sure what would go here if anything
  )
  ) AS pvt
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Austin.

Comment: Be careful with tagging your question because the code in the question is for ms sql server, not mysql!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I figured it out.  Is was as simple as using the DISTINCT function. As I said, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to scripting.  So for those who read this post, the answer is as follows (the ORDER BY is extra)...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[iModelTable]
,[FieldName]
FROM [H352090DataMart].[dbo].[HA_iModelTableData]
ORDER BY iModelTable
```